# jquery strip date format

Tags: jquery, time

some time ago i find out that i can use this to convert the time from this `1273185387`format:

```
var myObj = $.parseJSON('{"date_created":"1273185387"}'),
myDate = new Date(1000*myObj.date_created);

console.log(myDate.toString());
console.log(myDate.toLocaleString());
console.log(myDate.toUTCString());
```

and the results are:

```
Thu May 06 2010 15:36:27 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
Thursday, May 06, 2010 3:36:27 PM
Thu, 06 May 2010 22:36:27 GMT
```

what if i want to strip the date somehow to show the `mm-dd-yyyy` or only the `time`?

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var date = myDate.getDate();
var month = myDate.getMonth();
var year = myDate.getFullYear();

console.log(date + "-" + month + "-" + year);

var hours = myDate.getHours();
var minutes = myDate.getMinutes();

console.log(hours + ":" + minutes);
```

Here's a nice article that gives an overview on [Working With Dates](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/)

#### Plug for using [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)

You may not be in the market for an entire Javascript library, but Date.js is amazing! It adds tons of intuitive functions that make working with dates in javascript very easy.

It provides a `.toString()` method which allows you to specify the format easily. Here's some examples:

```
Date.today().toString();           // native .toString() functionality
Date.today().toString("M/d/yyyy"); // 11/19/2007
Date.today().toString("d-MMM-yyyy"); // 19-Nov-2007
new Date().toString("HH:mm");      // 18:45
```

Answer (score 1):

jessegavin's answer is almost right, but the date format he returns is `d-m-yyyy`, not `mm-dd-yyyy`. Also, the `getMonth()` function returns a value between `0-11`, so you would need to add `1` to it. Here's a quick function for the `mm-dd-yyyy` format:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    mm = (mm < 10) ? '0' + mm : mm;
    return mm + "-" + dd + "-" + yyyy;
}
```

The second-to-last line uses the ternary operator to check if the month is less than `10`, and if it is, prepend `0` to it.

Edit: Date.js looks pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

See JavaScript reference for [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). For example you can use `myDate.toTimeString()` to get the time portion.